# What does the term "kerplewy" mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

What does the term mean and what is the best way to use it? And, I also wanted to know if there is any information about where it comes from. And by the way, how do we pronounce it?

Comment: Pronunciation:  ker-PLOO-ee.  (I normally see it spelled as "kerplooey".)

Comment: I spell it kaplooie if I have to spell it at all. The ker- vs ka- is probably about being rhotic or not. I don't think either group sounds the R in it.

Comment: Also spelled Kablooie (it probably needs some capitalization in usage)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an onomatopoeic term for an explosion or perhaps something collapsing in an horrendous cascade of messiness.

> Things were going well until lunch, and then a bunch of error reports made my whole day go kerplewy. [My day got messed up badly].
>
> The children's room is kerplewy. [The room is such a mess that explosions are referenced as hyperbole].

It use is normally half-joking, certainly informal.

A variant is *kablooie* as in "Horrendous Space Kablooie", a term used in a comic for the Big Bang that some scientists prefer. Mostly because they have a sense of humour, but also because "Big Bang" was coined to ridicule the theory, not to name it.

Comment: The variant that seems to be included in by far the most dictionaries is *kerflooey*. Merriam-Webster dates it back to 1918. Wiktionary lists the alternative spellings *kerflewie* and *kerflewy*.

Comment: I think [kablooey](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kablooey?q=kablooey) is the more usual spelling.

Comment: @RegDwighт I would interpret that slightly differently - less explosive and more a matter of falling apart. It's perhaps reasonable to say "they're much the same, but sound different" since sound is obviously key to an onomatopoeic word.

Comment: @MattЭллен Google ngrams seems to agree with you in favouring *kablooey* over *kablooie*, though in talking about the HSK it's more often *kablooie* since that was the spelling used in the Calvin and Hobbes cartoon that coined it.

Comment: Matching what @Matt says, COCA has 9 *kablooey*, 6 *kerflooey*, 3 *kablooie*, 0 *kerflewy*, 0 *kerplewy*. COHA has 4, 0, 1, 0, 0. BNC has no hits for anything.

Answer (score 10):

**kerplewy** is **ker-** + **blooey**. The *OED* says:

> **ker-**, *prefix*. Forms:  Also occasionally **ke-**, **ca-**, **ka-**, **che-**, **co-**. *U.S. vulgar.* The first element in numerous onomatopœic or echoic formations intended to imitate the sound or the effect of the fall of some heavy body, as ***kerchunk***, ***kerflop***, ***kerplunk***, ***kerslam***, ***kerslap***, ***kerslash***, ***kersouse***, ***kerswash***, ***kerswosh***, ***kerthump***, ***kerwhop***, etc.

And:

> **blooey**, *adj.* Forms:  Also **blooie**. *U.S. slang.* Awry, amiss.

Comment: I would take that *vulgar* cum grano salis, and think more of the vulgus than of coarse slang.

Comment: I've never heard of *kersouse*.

Comment: @Jim: 1856   *Yankee Notions* 180   I had my shoulders drawn up, my head down, my eyes and teeth shut, when kersouse came a hull ocean of ice-water.

Comment: @GarethRees Thanks for your kindness. You helped me alot