# I need a definition of, usage and correct spelling of caplui

Tags: meaning, word-usage, orthography, onomatopoeia

I may be spelling this wrong or this may be a poor version of the word but I am looking for the spelling and meaning of the word caploui

I am trying to use it in a sentence like ' and all of a sudden, everything went caplui'

I do not want to use kaput

Any help you can give would be appreciated

Comment: http://calvinandhobbes.wikia.com/wiki/Hamster_Huey_and_the_Gooey_Kablooie

Comment: Related: [What does the term “kerplewy” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100365)

Comment: ......kaplooie.

Comment: @Spencer I'm guessing without clicking your link that it's Hamster Huey and the Gooey Kablooie! Which is the absolute only cultural or other reference I have for the word...

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be most often spelled [***kablooie***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kablooie#English) or **kablooey** (Wiktionary prefers the former, while [Google's Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kablooie%2Ckablooey&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckablooie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckablooey%3B%2Cc0) and I prefer the latter).

However, I don't know that there's a perfectly standardized spelling. In addition to the aforementioned two, Wiktionary also suggests each with a hyphen (*ka-blooey* etc.) plus *kerblooie* and *kerplooie*, which are presumably preferred by folks whose dialect includes ["intrusive R"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R), and at least two others have come up in comments. The only thing they seem to have in common is that they generally begin with a *k*.

> **Noun**
> **kablooie** (*uncountable*)
>
> (*colloquial*) A failure, meltdown; or explosion; a splat or splash.
> The bottle of ketchup hit the floor and went kablooie all over everything.
> **Usage notes**
> Most frequently used in the phrase **to go kablooie** or **it went kablooie**.

Your usage looks spot-on for the definition, assuming you mean that the situation suddenly and dramatically went wrong; I would write it:

> All of a sudden, everything went **kablooey**.

However, if you have a strong preference for another spelling I wouldn't call it wrong.